# How to tamper a X509 format certificate?

Tags: openssl, x509certificate, pki

I used openssl command line tool to generate a CA signed certificate. now I need to tamper it to generate the signature mismatch error.

Is there any tool available to tamper the X509 certificate.

Comment: here are the locations of the stores, if you are using Windows. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388136(v=vs.85).aspx . Find your store and look for a key that matches your thumbprint. If you modify the blob i think that should do it.

Comment: @Brandon.Staley can you tell me how to modify the blob

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open certificate file in [ASN.1 Editor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4910/ASN-1-Editor), find commonName node, right-click it and choose "Edit...":

[image]

Change the text of commonName field:

[image]

Hit OK, save your changes and there you are:

[image]

Comment: How to prevent this tampering?